# Writing Test Results to Excel using Selenium

Tags: java, excel, selenium, apache-poi, testng

I've done plenty of research on this question and have tried many different methods, but none of them do what I'd like, or the explanations to implement them into my own code are really vague.

I need to export the test results (TestID, Expected Result, Pass or Fail) into an excel sheet. I am currently using TestNG and Apache POI.

I know how to write to an excel sheet, but I am absolutely lost on how to write whether or not something passed or failed. I am currently using some code that doesn't exactly work - sometimes it will write it, sometimes it won't. I need the most simple, easy way to do this, with a good explanation.

I'll show you my current `@BeforeClass`, `@AfterClass`, and two `@Test` blocks.

`@BeforeClass`:

```
@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setupBeforeSuite(ITestContext context) throws IOException {
        //create a new work book
        workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        //create a new work sheet
        sheet = workbook.createSheet("Test Result");
        testresultdata = new LinkedHashMap < String, Object[] > ();
        //add test result excel file column header
        //write the header in the first row
        testresultdata.put("1", new Object[] {
            "Test Step Id", "Action", "Expected Result", "Actual Result"
        });

    }
```

`@AfterClass`:

```
@AfterClass
      public void setupAfterSuite(ITestContext context) {
        //write excel file and file name is TestResult.xls 
        Set<String> keyset = testresultdata.keySet();
        int rownum = 0;
        for (String key : keyset) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
            Object [] objArr = testresultdata.get(key);
            int cellnum = 0;
            for (Object obj : objArr) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
                if(obj instanceof Date) 
                    cell.setCellValue((Date)obj);
                else if(obj instanceof Boolean)
                    cell.setCellValue((Boolean)obj);
                else if(obj instanceof String)
                    cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
                else if(obj instanceof Double)
                    cell.setCellValue((Double)obj);
            }
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream out =new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/Users/PathToFile/LoginCombinations.xls"));
            workbook.write(out);
            out.close();
            System.out.println("Excel written successfully..");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

`@Test` blocks:

```
@Test(priority=0)
    public void successfulLogin() throws InterruptedException {

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream config = null;
        InputStream signinpage;

        try {
            // First we iterate over and read the config file
            config = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/PathToFile/src/ConfigFiles/config");
            prop.load(config);
            signinpage = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/PathToFile/src/ObjectRepositories/signinpage");
            prop.load(signinpage);

            // Next we initiate the driver, and navigate to the Web Application
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            // Now we run the first step, "enterValidCredentials"
            // In this test, this is actually the only step.
            LoginPage.enterValidCredentials.run(driver);

            // Assert that we landed on the Product Select page.
            // assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("tempproductselect"))).getText(), "SELECT PRODUCT");
            try{
                assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("tempproductselect"))).getText(), "SELECT PRODUCT");
                  //add pass entry to the excel sheet
                  testresultdata.put("2", new Object[] {1d, "User can login with a valid username and password", "Login successful","Pass"});
                  }

                  catch(Exception e)
                  {
                    //add fail entry to the excel sheet
                    testresultdata.put("2", new Object[] {1d, "User can login with a valid username and password", "Login successful","Fail"});
                  }

            // Write the test result to the sheet.

            driver.close();
            Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
            alert.accept();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (config != null) {
                try {
                    config.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

    }

@Test(priority=1)
    public void invalidCredentialsOne() throws InterruptedException {

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream config = null;
        InputStream signinpage;

        try {
            // First we iterate over and read the config file
            config = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/PathToFile/src/ConfigFiles/config");
            prop.load(config);
            signinpage = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/PathToFile/src/ObjectRepositories/signinpage");
            prop.load(signinpage);

            // Next we initiate the driver, and navigate to the Web Application
            WebDriver driver;
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            // Now we run the first step, "invalidCredentialsOne"
            // In this test, this is actually the only step.
            LoginPage.invalidCredentialsOne.run(driver);
            Thread.sleep(5000);

            try{
                assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("failedlogin"))).getText(), "LOG IN");
              //add pass entry to the excel sheet
                testresultdata.put("3", new Object[] {2d, "User should not be able to login with an invalid password", "Login failed","Pass"});
              }

              catch(Exception e)
              {
                //add fail entry to the excel sheet
                testresultdata.put("3", new Object[] {2d, "User should not be able to login with an invalid password", "Login failed","Fail"});
              }           

            // Write the test result to the sheet.

            // After the test, we close the driver.
            driver.close();
            Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
            alert.accept();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (config != null) {
                try {
                    config.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

The second test, invalidCredentialsOne, never writes to the excel, whether I make it pass or fail.

Java is also new to me, so forgive any formatting/lingo/whatever errors I have in there. I'm very open-minded to suggestion, I'm trying to improve.

Comment: What makes you use .xls extention ? Consider saving them as CSV as: "Test Step Id", "Action", "Expected Result", "Actual Result" . When you'll open it in excel, it will be separated on columns automatically. For writing in file i use:

BufferedWriter outputWriter;
        outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:/zz/zz.txt"));  
 outputWriter.write("Your parameters");

Comment: @DmitryMalinovsky Manager's preference, really. CSV could definitely work, I'd have to learn some more about BufferedWriter (if you have any legitimately good tutorials on writing test results into CSV, send them this way).

Comment: Np, mate, i've had same issue last week. http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/qanda/pjqa00009.shtml this is the article that i conducted by

Comment: If anyone has some fully explained examples of how I could structure my `BeforeClass`, `AfterClass` and two `Test` blocks into writing effective CSV files, I'd definitely accept that as an answer. The hardest part for me isn't understanding the code, it's implementing it piece by piece into my framework.

Comment: Hi @jagdpanzer i need your help. As per your before class, how can we add testresultdata values to excel sheet. i am new to selenium. please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the structure as i see it:

1) A part where you have a [DriverFactory](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm) defined.

```
public class BrowserFactory {

public static WebDriver localDriver(Capabilities capabilities) {
String browserType = capabilities.getBrowserName();
if (browserType.equals("firefox"))
  return new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
if (browserType.startsWith("internet explorer"))
  return new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
if (browserType.equals("chrome"))
  return new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
throw new Error("Unrecognized browser type: " + browserType);
}
```

Then you can simply initialize it anytime you need it : 
Example:

```
driver = BrowserFactory.localDriver(DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
```

2) Your test classes, where you use this factory. Then there will be no need in @BeforeClass annotations. You write your tests in those classes. And at the end of every test, you make an assert (if test result failed or not). To check if the test passes, use the Assert.true(); 
Example: I i use the wrokg credentials on login, the allert: Wrong Password will appear.

Solution: You make an Assert.true(errorMessagePresent)

3) Your output writer class - to make it accessible for your tests

3) In case the test passes - you add the string you want to the output, using the buffer reader, else you throw an exception

Comment: I'm a fan of the DriverFactory design you mentioned. Thanks for that. I could probably put the outputWriter into my main class so it would apply to the rest of the code, right? Also, would I use the bufferedWriter in the same way I'm using the excel writer right now (i.e, try/catch blocks with Assertion methods)? Makes a lot of sense, and seems a whole lot easier than writing to xls. Thanks for the input.

Comment: If you're interested i can share with you a proper factory pattern, that will eliminate all possible exceptions and failures. Makes the working process more simple

Comment: There you go. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6xuH_1NbS0UaWhoZ1ZqTTlMN0k/view?usp=sharing  , if you'll have any questions, do not hesitate to ask. Cheers

Comment: Thank you so much. You've improved my job performance and coding standards practically overnight. I appreciate it! You  should consider putting that drive file on the community wiki - it'd be a great resource.